# Android Button vs TextView - Hyperlink like behavior

Tags: java, android

On an Android View, I want to have a some clickable text that works similar to a webpage hyperlink.

It looks just like normal text (no button border), but when touched, I want the text color to change and I may also want its background to turn a reverse color.

Is it better to use a Button with a transparent background or a TextView. When should I choose one over the other?

Thanks much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hotveryspicy gave a great answer and really pointed me in the right direction. Thank you, but I had a few issues with the response.

What I want is a button that has Black text and a Gray background in its normal state and a Red background with White text in its selected state. Like this:

[image]

Using hotveryspicy's suggestions I had the following issues:

1. I get an error when trying to assign a drawable to textColor. Funny but I see other references to doing this sort of thing. Maybe the XML validation is stricter now?
2. I also got an error if I didn't define a android:drawable in the buttonselector.xml. It seems you can set the color of a drawable in a selector eiter, you need to actually create a drawable.

Anyhow this is what I did:

I created a [Color State Resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html) that looks like this:

File: res/colors/link_button.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#ffffff"/> 
    <item android:color="#000000"/> 
</selector>
```

Then the following 3 drawables:

My button background in its normal state using a [Shape Drawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape):
File: res/drawable/link_button.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid  android:color="#cccccc"/>
</shape>
```

My button background in its selected state, also a [Shape Drawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape):
File: res/drawable/link_button_selected.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid  android:color="#ff0000"/>
</shape>
```

Then I created a [Drawable Selector](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList) that chooses between the 2 shapes.
File: res/drawable/link_button_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

 <item 
     android:drawable="@drawable/link_button_selected"
     android:state_pressed="true" />

 <item 
     android:drawable="@drawable/link_button" />
</selector>
```

Then in my layout my button looks like this:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="Button"
    android:textColor="@color/link_button" 
    android:background="@drawable/link_button_selector"
    />
```

Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: It is may be because of older version of ADT you are using, as the same `@drawable` working fine for me :) All in all your problem resolved that matters. +1

Answer (score 3):

you can use Button and make `selector` for background and text both.

textselector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#0000ff"/> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="@android:color/white"/> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:color="@android:color/white"/> <!-- default -->

</selector>
```

buttonselector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@android:color/white"/> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="#0000ff"/> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:color="#0000ff"/> <!-- default -->

</selector>
```

In your layout xml

```
<Button
     android:id="@+id/button"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:background="@drawable/buttonselector"
     android:text="some text"
     android:textColor="@drawable/textselector" />
```

Comment: Thanks but this didn't quite work for me. I get an error when I try to assign a drawable to a textColor. I'm going to post my solution below.

Comment: neat -- I never thought to use a selector for text color. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Add String like

```
  <string name="link">'<a href="http://www.google.com" rel="nofollow">Google</a>'</string>
```

In your layout

```
<TextView  
          android:id="@+id/link"  
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
          android:autoLink="all"  
          android:linksClickable="true"  
          android:text="@string/link" />
```

Comment: OP also want to change background.

Answer (score 1):

You can linkify your text using the linkify class.
Have a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/wikinotes-linkify.html) and [this with few examples](http://mobile.dzone.com/news/android-%E2%80%93-creating-links-using)

Answer (score 1):

For Google's sake:

Rather than make a button look like a link why not make a TextView clickable?  This was effectively what I wanted and worked for my use.  I wanted text to be clickable to spawn an intent.

```
TextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
```